# android how to select the some part of the photo (crop in different types /different shapes)

Tags: android

I want to know how to select different shapes selection of image. When i am cropping the image it is only accepting the rectangle/square shape model not more than that. i want to accept the in different shapes. is there is any way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you find solution for that please share here...